# C#: how to set DNS resolve timeout?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if a host can be resolved，but I don't want to wait a long time; so I want to set a timeout.

I have tried

```
 public static bool ResolveTest(string hostNameOrAddress, TimeSpan time_out)
 {
     var result = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress, null, null);
     var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(time_out);
     if (!success) {
         //throw new Exception("Failed to resolve the domain.");
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

but this is not working correctly, because when it's a wrong host, it also can return true. So how to set a timeout for DnsResolve?

Comment: answer has been updated with a better looking version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Answer**

*look at the updated answer*

There is no way of actually cancelling the `Dns.BeginGetHostEntry()` but you could try to implement something that can be cancelled after a set time. This is slightly hackish but can do as you have asked.

However DNS lookups are (typically) really fast and in tests typically resolve within 10ms.

Here is a sample. Basically making a `Task` based approach that allows you to execute a `Task` which returns a bool whether the result was completed.

```
public static Task<bool> Resolve(string hostNameOrAddress, int millisecond_time_out)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        bool completed = false;
        var asCallBack = new AsyncCallback(ar =>
        {
            ResolveState context = (ResolveState)ar.AsyncState;
            if (context.Result == ResolveType.Pending)
            {
                try
                {
                    var ipList = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(ar);
                    if (ipList == null || ipList.AddressList == null || ipList.AddressList.Length == 0)
                        context.Result = ResolveType.InvalidHost;
                    else
                        context.Result = ResolveType.Completed;
                }
                catch
                {
                    context.Result = ResolveType.InvalidHost;
                }
            }
            completed = true;
        });
        ResolveState ioContext = new ResolveState(hostNameOrAddress);
        var result = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(ioContext.HostName, asCallBack, ioContext);
        int miliCount = 0;
        while (!completed)
        {
            miliCount++;
            if (miliCount >= millisecond_time_out)
            {
                result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
                result = null;
                ioContext.Result = ResolveType.Timeout;
                break;
            }
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"The result of {ioContext.HostName} is {ioContext.Result}");
        return ioContext.Result == ResolveType.Completed;
    });
}

public class ResolveState
{
    public ResolveState(string hostName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostName));
        _hostName = hostName;
    }

    readonly string _hostName;

    public ResolveType Result { get; set; } = ResolveType.Pending;

    public string HostName => _hostName;

}

public enum ResolveType
{
    Pending,
    Completed,
    InvalidHost,
    Timeout
}
```

The method can then be called as

```
public static async void RunTest()
{
    await Resolve("asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa.ca", 60);
    await Resolve("google.com", 60);
}
```

When the Resolve is executed it creates an internal `AsyncCallBack` delegate. This delegate is then passed to the `Dns.BeginGetHostEntry()` method. In addition we pass in a `state` object of `ResolveState`. This state object is resposible for managing the state between the contexts. Therefore when the `AsyncCallBack` gets executed we can set the `Result` of the `ResolveState`. Next the `completed` flag is set to indicate the callback delegate completed.

Finally (and this is the part I dont like) is we then have a loop that executes every `1ms` and if the timeout expires sets the `Result` of our state object to `Timeout`.

Again this is slightly hackish but does result in sort of the desired effect. Now this is also done `async` so you can use the `async` & `await` features.

**Updated Answer**

After the first answer I didnt like the result and reviewed your initial question. You were on the right track except we need to check the complete flag as you have done. However `success` will return false if `result` didn't finish after the `WaitOne` call. If it finished then `success` will be `true` (even without resolving the IP address) you then need to check the result using the `Dns.EndGetHostEntry`.

Revised Code:

```
public static bool ResolveTest(string hostNameOrAddress, int millisecond_time_out)
{
    ResolveState ioContext = new ResolveState(hostNameOrAddress);
    var result = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(ioContext.HostName, null, null);
    var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecond_time_out), true);
    if (!success)
    {
        ioContext.Result = ResolveType.Timeout;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            var ipList = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(result);
            if (ipList == null || ipList.AddressList == null || ipList.AddressList.Length == 0)
                ioContext.Result = ResolveType.InvalidHost;
            else
                ioContext.Result = ResolveType.Completed;
        }
        catch
        {
            ioContext.Result = ResolveType.InvalidHost;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"The result of ResolveTest for {ioContext.HostName} is {ioContext.Result}");
    return ioContext.Result == ResolveType.Completed;
}
```

Here's the full gist https://gist.github.com/Nico-VanHaaster/35342c1386de752674d0c37ceaa65e00.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate solution, the NuGet library [DNS Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DnsClient/) allows configuring the request timeout.

Usage:

```
var dns = new DnsClient.LookupClient();
dns.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
dns.ThrowDnsErrors = true;

//will succeed
var dnsResult1 = dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");

//will throw an exception; or, if ThrowDnsErrors is false, return null
var dnsResult2 = dns.GetHostEntry("bogus");
```

Answer (score 3):

To improve on the answer by knocte, the code can be further simplified by using the provided `System.Net.DNS.GetHostAddressesAsync` thus removing the need to write your own async function. For example:

```
    private string ResolveWithTimeout(string hostName)
    {
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0);
        var task = System.Net.DNS.GetHostAddressesAsync(hostName);
        if (!task.Wait(timeout))
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
        return task.Result[0].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Current accepted answer is quite old and complex, nowadays you can easily use `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run()` for this, this way:

```
private Task<IPAddress> ResolveAsync(string hostName) {
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
        return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0];
    });
}

private string ResolveWithTimeout(string hostNameOrIpAddress) {
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0);
    var task = ResolveAsync(hostNameOrIpAddress);
    if (!task.Wait(timeout)) {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
    return task.Result.ToString();
}
```